# Flutter Stay on same y-axis after s navigating back to the previous scrolled Homescreen

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to find a solution to come back to the exact same y-axis when I navigate from one screen back to my Homescreen. I have a list of cards on my Homescreen and when I want to choose the last card, I have to scroll down in order to tap it. But when I'm pressing the back button I always land back on the top position of that Homescreen.

Here's the ListView, which is wrapped inside an AnimatedContainer(I have a DrawerScreen implemented)

```
ListView(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              secondcard(
                                "Alphabet",
                                titel[0],
                                items[0],
                                pictures[0],
                                descriptions[0],
                                colours4[0],
                                colours1[0],
                                colours2[0],
                                colours3[0],
                              ),
                              card(
                                "Begrüßungen",
                                titel[1],
                                items[1],
                                pictures[1],
                                descriptions[1],
                                colours1[1],
                                colours2[1],
                                colours3[1],
                                colours4[1],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              card(
                                "Einkaufen",
                                titel[1],
                                items[2],
                                pictures[2],
                                descriptions[2],
                                colours1[2],
                                colours2[2],
                                colours3[2],
                                colours4[2],
                              ),
                              card(
                                "Farben",
                                titel[1],
                                items[3],
                                pictures[3],
                                descriptions[3],
                                colours1[0],
                                colours2[0],
                                colours3[0],
                                colours4[0],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              card(
                                "Fragewörter",
                                titel[1],
                                items[4],
                                pictures[4],
                                descriptions[4],
                                colours1[1],
                                colours2[1],
                                colours3[1],
                                colours4[1],
                              ),
                              card(
                                "Konversation",
                                titel[1],
                                items[5],
                                pictures[5],
                                descriptions[5],
                                colours1[2],
                                colours2[2],
                                colours3[2],
                                colours4[2],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              card(
                                "Lebensmittel",
                                titel[1],
                                items[6],
                                pictures[6],
                                descriptions[6],
                                colours1[0],
                                colours2[0],
                                colours3[0],
                                colours4[0],
                              ),
                              card(
                                "Richtungsangaben",
                                titel[1],
                                items[7],
                                pictures[7],
                                descriptions[7],
                                colours1[1],
                                colours2[1],
                                colours3[1],
                                colours4[1],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              card(
                                "Tiere",
                                titel[1],
                                items[8],
                                pictures[8],
                                descriptions[8],
                                colours1[2],
                                colours2[2],
                                colours3[2],
                                colours4[2],
                              ),
                              card(
                                "Über mich",
                                titel[1],
                                items[9],
                                pictures[9],
                                descriptions[9],
                                colours1[0],
                                colours2[0],
                                colours3[0],
                                colours4[0],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              card(
                                "wegweisung",
                                titel[1],
                                items[10],
                                pictures[10],
                                descriptions[10],
                                colours1[1],
                                colours2[1],
                                colours3[1],
                                colours4[1],
                              ),
                              card(
                                "Wochentage",
                                titel[1],
                                items[11],
                                pictures[11],
                                descriptions[11],
                                colours1[2],
                                colours2[2],
                                colours3[2],
                                colours4[2],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              thirdcard(
                                "Zahlen",
                                titel[1],
                                items[13],
                                pictures[13],
                                descriptions[13],
                                colours1[1],
                                colours2[1],
                                colours3[1],
                                colours4[1],
                              ),
                              card(
                                "Zeitangaben",
                                titel[1],
                                items[12],
                                pictures[12],
                                descriptions[12],
                                colours1[0],
                                colours2[0],
                                colours3[0],
                                colours4[0],
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
```

The back button only does a pushNamed navigation, because I haven't found anything that comes close to my desired functionality after trying a few dozen possible solutions.

Sadly none of them worked.

Comment: Please show a full code of your widget containing this ListView

Comment: Hey Kerim, the widget is to big to post it here. :/